# Is using 'like' a possibility in TestComplete?

Tags: string, if-statement, similarity, jscript, testcomplete

How do I write an if statement that searches for a similarity, rather than a direct result?

For example, I want to search for labels that begin with ABC:

```
if(label == 'ABC') //but I have two other labels: 'ABC1' and 'ABC2'
```

Is there a way to do something like: (if label like 'ABC'), instead of three separate if statements? I know I could else if() if I need to, but I want to avoid hard coding labels since they can be added, deleted, updated, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```js
var label = 'ABC'
if (label.match(/abc[12]?/i)) console.log('yes')
else console.log('no')
```